# Magento Shipping/Payment Reset

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm not sure whether this is a bug or what, I have bought an extension online, then inside the quote the amount was set and other required data are set inside, everything goes fine, until I call /cart/mine/shipping-information, everything was being reset like normal.

[image: If you see the image, the left] check above screenshot is before calling shipping-information API, after calling the API, the right side is being reset like normal without any discount being deducted. Any reason why it become like this?

Just a note, front end is working fine, only API is the one causing the problem.

Comment: what is the magento version ?

Comment: @RaviChaudhary It is Magento v2.15

Comment: Okay let me try this, will get back to you soon